# VBA Access: Defining arrays

Tags: ms-access, vba

My question is, do I have to define the dimensions of an array or can the size of an array change dynamically?

I have a form with a subform with a yes/no boxes. I have a recordset object that subsets the data of the form to just the rows where the boxes are selected Yes.

I loop through the recordset and append the value to a string.

I'd rather iterate through the recordset and put the values into an array, except I don't know how many boxes the user will select, so I can't predict the length of the array when I define it.

I've tried doing things like

```
dim myArray(0 to variableEqualToLengthOfRecordset) as variant
```

But it tells me I need a constant value in the statement.

Does anyone know if there is a way for me to set the length of my array dynamically?

If I simply define it as

```
dim myArray() as variant
```

I get an out of bounds error when I try to add values.

Comment: If you *"append the value to a string"* with a consistent separator between the values in that string --- like *value1;value2;value3* --- you can then `Split()` the string into an array and that array will be automatically right-sized: `varArray = Split(YourStringVariable, ";")`  If you really need to dimension the array explicitly, you can first `Dim` to an arbitrary size and later `ReDim` as needed.  See the Access help topics.

Comment: That occurred to me. How do I declare varArray in your example. Dim varArray() as variant?

Comment: With just `Dim varArray As Variant`, it will accept the array returned from `Split()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theres multiple ways to do this but in short, yes you can define the array as well as redefine it dynamically. 
To redefine use Redim varArray or simply overwrite the variable.
Heres a little example of what I use when I dont know the strings length

```
Dim varArray as String

varArray = Split(String, " ") ' Or whatever type it is and its delimiter.

'Then just cycle through the array with a for loop

for Counter = LBount(varArray) to UBound(array)
    string = string + varArray(counter)

next counter
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can redefine the the array with ReDim Preserve intArray() but this is very costly and will slow your program. I would recommend just making the array the Maximum size, and put blanks in when they do not check a box or nothing, and then just put a If Array(I) = "" then  do nothing or something. Unless you are getting an array larger that 1,000,000 i doubt you will have any issues.